# jQuery addClass() works only when there is an alert() box before it

Tags: jquery, jsp, addclass, event-bubbling

I have button as below-

```
<input type="button" onclick="validateAllAnswers(event);" value="Submit" id="tab_button1" class="btn btn-info"/>

function validateAllAnswers(e) {
    var isCompleteTabOne = true;
    var isCompleteTabTwo = true;
    var isCompleteTabThree = true;
    var flag = true;
    if (isCompleteTabOne == false && isCompleteTabTwo == false) {
        flag = false;
        alert("You missed a question(s) in Questionnaire One. Please answer before submitting the quiz!");
        document.getElementById("TabQuestionnaireOne").click()
        $("#TabQuestionnaireOne").addClass("active");
        for (var i = 0; i < noQuestionsTabOne; i++) {
            if (!($('input[name=tab1_radio_' + i + ']').is(':checked'))) {
                alert("111")
                e.stopPropagation();
                $('label[id=highlight_tabOne_' + i + ']').addClass('highlighter');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Problem: The addClass method works perfectly fine when I have an alert() before it. But, no color is getting changed without alert(). Also, I tried using event.stopPropagation(). That didn't solve my problem.Can someone let me know what I am missing here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It appears that your form is getting submitted, then the page reloads thereby clearing form and also aborting any script that may have been triggered by the submit. *Plus, you're better off listening for the form's submit event as there may be other ways that trigger the event, eg ENTER key, among other reasons*

A better approach would be:

```
<!--HTML-->
<form id="myform" action="...." ...>
.....
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="tab_button1" class="btn btn-info"/>
</form>

//JS
$(function() {
    $('#myform').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //your code goes here
        //you may also want count any unfilled fields and use e.preventDefault()
        //if the # is greater than zero
        //OR use e.preventDefault() at the top
        //then use this.submit() if all fields are filled/provided/checked
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`onclick=" event.preventDefault();validateAllAnswers(event);"` . you must stop form from submitting. then only the function will work properly. after validation you have to submit the from manually using `$("form")[0].submit()`

Comment: Hi, I tried having event.preventDefault() in the onClick event. It's still not working and no color is changed. I also tried it with- <input type="submit" onclick="event.preventDefault();validateAllAnswers(event);" value="Submit" id="tab_button1"/>

Answer (score 0):

I think your code will not validate, see the piece of code,

```
var isCompleteTabOne = true;
var isCompleteTabTwo = true;
var isCompleteTabThree = true;
var flag = true;
// isCompleteTabOne and isCompleteTabTwo both are true here
if(isCompleteTabOne == false && isCompleteTabTwo == false)
```

Also if you are using `jquery` then use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) to bind click event like,

```
$(function(){
    $('#tab_button1').on('click',function(){
        // your validation code
    });
});
```

As you are using a button so there is not need of preventing the default behavior also there is no parent elements so avoid the use of `stopPropagation()`

Comment: What if the form is submitting because there is nothing stopping it (ie, an alert) and the OP is missing the addClass actually happening?

Answer (score 0):

What I *think* is happening is that the form is submitting without you *noticing* the addClass. When you alert something it will temporarily halt the execution. So, you can see the change. We need to stop the submission so you can see the change. Does that sound correct?

You could *try* to add a `return false;` in the function... Ie;

```
function validateAllAnswers(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // Do whatever
  return false;
}
```

That will stop the redirection/submission from occurring.

You can then add any code between the two and submit if you need to after validating.